# Connecting with sharepoint site using CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

my code is like below

```
  try
    {

        string strUserName="abc";
        string strPassword="123";
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteurl);
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUserName, strPassword,"Ext");


        context.Credentials = credentials;
        // The SharePoint web at the URL.
        Web web = context.Web;

        // We want to retrieve the web's properties.
        context.Load(web);

        // Execute the query to the server.
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        // Now, the web's properties are available and we could display 
        // web properties, such as title. 
        System.Console.WriteLine("Web Title");
        System.Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

it is giving error "unable to connect remote server"

Comment: guess your user name doesnot have enough permission to access the site. you can check your detailed error info and its call stack to get a clue

Comment: its having permission and i am able to access with these credential when i access from browser. from c# its giving error "the remote certificate is invalid accoarding to validation process, could not establish trust relationship for the ssl/tls secure channel"

Comment: there is no sharepoint installed in my pc. you have checked your sharepoint log?this error message may be related to the certificate  validation between your client and sharepoint

Comment: What is the value of siteurl?

Answer (score 1):

First thing make sure that the following entities are correctly passed:

- siteurl
- strUserName
- strPassword
- "Ext"

If you're trying to connect to SharePoint Online 2013 then you have to replace, "NetworkCredential" with "[SharePointOnlineCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.sharepointonlinecredentials(v=office.15).aspx)". Here's the code snippet for it:

```
    string strUserName="abc";
    string strPassword="123";
    SecureString ssPwd = new SecureString();
    strPassword.ToList().ForEach(ssPwd.AppendChar);
    ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteurl);
    SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(strUserName, ssPwd);

    context.Credentials = credentials;
    // The SharePoint web at the URL.
    Web web = context.Web;

    // We want to retrieve the web's properties.
    context.Load(web);

    // Execute the query to the server.
    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: its not on sharepoint 2013. it is giving detail exception "the remote certificate is invalid accoarding to validation process, could not establish trust relationship for the ssl/tls secure channel"

Answer (score 0):

To accept self signed certificates :

`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;`